# RAII locking with condition

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, raii

I have a piece of code which needs to be protected by a lock only if some condition is true.

```
if(condition) {

   std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(some_mutex);

   // do a bunch of things

} else {

   // do a bunch of things
}
```

Although I can move all of the `// bunch of things`  in a separate function and call that, I was wondering if there is an RAII way that would allow to take the lock conditionally.

Something like

```
if(condition){

   // the lock is taken
}

// do a bunch of things

// lock is automatically released if it was taken
```

Comment: My nose tells me that `condition` is probably being passed in as a function argument. If true, you’re probably better off making it two functions.

Comment: I am afraid that's not the case. It's a config value that is set in some remote corner of the code base.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can switch to using a [`std::unique_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) and use its [`std::defer_lock_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_tag_t) tagged constructor.  This will start with the mutex unlocked, but you can then use its [`lock()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/lock) method to lock the mutex, which will then be released by the destructor.  That would give you a code flow that looks like this:

```
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(some_mutex, std::defer_lock_t{});
    if (mutex_should_be_locked)
    {
        guard.lock();
    }
    // rest of code 
} // scope exit, unlock will be called if the mutex was locked
```